# « Ouistiti » : élision et liaison : pourquoi pas ?

Tags: prononciation, liaisons, élision

Selon un livre de grammaire que je possède, on ne fait ni élision ni liaison avec le mot « ouistiti » bien qu'il commence par une voyelle. Pourquoi ? Existe-t-il d'autres mots qui commencent par une voyelle et pour lesquels il n'y a pas d'élision ni de liaison ?
(Hormis *un*, *on*, *onzième* que je connais déjà.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les chiffres, les lettres et les onomatopées bloquent généralement les sandhis comme la liaison et l'élision. C'est également de plus en plus le cas des prénoms, mais l'usage est encore très erratique.

On dit donc le un et le onze comme noté dans la question (de même que le huit, dont le ⟨h⟩ est aussi peu étymologique que celui de l'huître et de l'huile); de A à Z /dəaazɛd/ et pas d'A à Z; les ouaf ouaf d'un chien /lɛwafwaf/.

Edit: J'ai oublié de mentionner les mots issus du verlan et certains sigles, qui bloquent également le sandhi: un truc de ouf, la FEB. Tout ça pour dire que le phénomène des h aspirés a pu commencer avec les mots commençant avec le son /h/ et donc un ⟨h⟩ ortographique, mais qu'une fois entré dans la langue, les locuteurs ont commencé à le manipuler et l'étendre à d'autre contextes.

Ouistiti est d'origine onomatopéique et a le comportement attendu d'un tel mot.

Answer (score 5):

En comparant avec d'autres mots commençant par "oui" ou "ouï", on constate qu'il n'y a pas d'élision si le son est prononcé /wi/ (j'imagine que les grammaires usuelles de français ne citent que *oui* et *ouistiti* parce que ce sont deux mots courants, les autres sont plus rares):

> Le ouistiti est dans une cage
>
> Le ouija est sur la table
>
> Je n'attends pas de oui comme réponse à ma question
>
> La recette de la ouiche lorraine
>
> Ce sondage montre qu'il y a une majorité de ouistes

On fait exception pour le verbe *ouïr* et ses formes conjuguées ainsi que pour le nom *ouïe*

> J'ouïs ce que tu dis
>
> L'ouïe est un des cinq sens

MAIS bizarrement, on ne fait pas l'élision avec *ouï-dire*

> Le ouï-dire à son sujet lui a fait du tort.

Par contre, il y a une élision si le son est prononcé /u.i/:

> L'ouisme est un phénomène linguistique

Un cas particulier: le mot *ouïghour*, qui commence par le son /ui/ ou /uj/, accepte les deux usages:

> Ils parlent l'ouïghour / ils parlent le ouïghour

Comment: Attention, la "ouiche lorraine" est une private joke réservée à un cercle d'initiés...

Comment: Une précision : *j'ouïs ce que tu dis* est au passé simple. Au présent c'est ***j'ois** ce que tu dis* et au futur *j'ouïrai ce que tu diras* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On ne fait pas la liaison pour les mots suivant, en particulier pour l'article indéfini « un »;

> oui, ouistiti, oued, ouais

Tous ces mots commencent par /w/ et le n de « un » est rejeté pour ainsi dire.

Malgré des exceptions (ouate, ouïe), il semble que la raison profonde qui fait que cette liaison n'est pas faite est à rechercher dans la phonologie. Ce n'est pas une coïncidence si en anglais avant les mots commençant par /w/, qui n'est pas tout à fait une voyelle phonétique (on l'appelle d'ailleurs une semi-voyelle aussi relativement à la prononciation de l'anglais), il faut normalement utiliser la forme « a  » de l'article indéfini au lieu de la forme « an », laquelle est usuelle lorsque l'article précède un mot commençant par une voyelle phonétique; il donc question encore du rejet du n. Il est fondamentalement question d'euphonie en anglais : /n/ avant /w/ n'est pas « pratique ». Lorsque l'on fait la liaison pour « une ouïe », on remarque que l'on ne prononce plus /w/, que l'on change en /ou/, même si le changement n'est pas parfait. En français aussi l'euphonie doit probablement jouer un rôle dans ce phénomène.

Answer (score 0):

Une exception à la règle évoquée dans les réponses précédentes, l'expression suivante bien connue :

> [P’têt ben **qu’oui**, p’têt ben qu’non](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%E2%80%99t%C3%AAt_ben_qu%E2%80%99oui,_p%E2%80%99t%C3%AAt_ben_qu%E2%80%99non)...