# "Vicinité" : peut-on utiliser le mot couramment ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, histoire, synonymes

Je me demande pourquoi le mot vicinité n'est pas répertorié dans TLFi.

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/vicinit%C3%A9

Son emploi est-il considéré comme un anglicisme (vicinity) ?

Comment: Je dirais bien qu'entre *voisinage, environs, proximité*... en a déjà plein de mot très usuels pour dire ce genre de truc non ?

Comment: Possiblement, la question que vous voulez vraiment poser serait  « Saurait-on pourquoi le mot « vicinité » est tombé en désuétude ? ».

Comment: Je ne saurais répondre pour _vicinité_. En revanche, l'adjectif est toujours en usage, quoique restreint à peu d'expressions, par exemple: _chemin vicinal_.

Comment: On dit proximité en français pour vicinity, très souvent. In the vicinity of the crime=A proximité du crime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Le mot « vicinité » est employé en français de nos jours mais dans un sens plus spécialisé que l'anglais *vicinity*. Et pourtant les anglais nous ont emprunté le mot au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle (1<sup>er</sup> emploi signalé en 1560 dans l'OED).

Mais le mot a bien été employé en français avec le sens de la proximité physicospatiale, on le trouve dans le *[Dictionnaire de l'ancienne langue française et de tous ses dialectes du IX<sup>e</sup> au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/vicinit%C3%A9)* de Godefroy . Mais son emploi tombe en désuétude en français moderne pour ne réapparaitre que dans la deuxième moitié du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle dans un sens spécialisé.

De nos jours le mot n'est **plus employé pour parler de la proximité physicospatiale** (comme en anglais) mais il est employé essentiellement en **linguistique** :

> Voisinage, proximité de sémantique (de notions, de concepts). (*Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*).

et en **psychologie** pour désigner la proximité entre voisins mais en couvrant  un champ plus large que la simple proximité physicospatiale. C'est le seul sens que donne le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vicinit%C3%A9).

Il me semble que le concept a été popularisé dans ce domaine par le psychosociologue Jean Maisonneuve qui a travaillé sur les liens et les réseaux amicaux. (*Psycho sociologie de l'amitié*, 1993,  [extrait](https://books.google.fr/books?id=QK92DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=vicinit%C3%A9&source=bl&ots=LyYjifJmQQ&sig=ACfU3U3ZPYYp04kAEl7rWJT9-xjRfHz7yA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicms2QhtXlAhUQ2BoKHVe7CgQ4ChDoATACegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=vicinit%C3%A9&f=false)), et peut-être a-t-il employé le mot parce qu'il s'appuyait au départ sur une étude étasunienne, toujours est-il qu'il a créé un concept que d'autres reprennent en mettant le mot entre guillemets.

> Jean Maisonneuve dans sa *Psychologie de l'amitié* (2004) [a regroupé] tous les modes de proximité dans l'espace entre deux individus (distance physique, canaux de communication, système d'activités communes..) sous le terme de « vicinité » et a posé la question du rapport entre ces modes de « vicinité » et la fréquence des liens amicaux établis.([Relations et communications interpersonnelles](https://books.google.fr/books?id=5Tt7CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT39&lpg=PT39&dq=vicinit%C3%A9&source=bl&ots=hHpDjn3lQN&sig=ACfU3U3mteoc-MeS-CJiKih6RlYCyeXNgA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicms2QhtXlAhUQ2BoKHVe7CgQ4ChDoATAGegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=vicinit%C3%A9&f=false), E. Marc, D. Picard, G. Fischer, 2015)

On observe un regain d'emploi du mot dans la deuxième moitié du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle et les quelques exemples que j'ai consultés ont donné l'emploi du mot dans le contexte de la psychosociologie.
[image: ngram vicinité]

Et pas seulement dans les livres, aussi sur internet, par exemple :

> La vicinité, qui désigne tous les modes de proximité dans l’espace, exerce une forte influence sur les choix et les liens amicaux. ([Passeport santé](https://www.passeportsante.net/fr/psychologie/Fiche.aspx?doc=amitie))

Il doit être possible de rencontrer le mot employé dans le sens anglais pour désigner une simple proximité physicospatiale mais beaucoup vont considérer que cet emploi est un anglicisme. Le mot ne se trouve pas dans mon édition du *Petit Robert* (déjà ancienne) mais peut-être ces emplois récents lui feront-ils retrouver une place dans les dictionnaires d'ici quelques décennies.

On emploie encore en français l'adjectif [vicinal](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vicinal), lequel, comme l'a précisé @aCOSwt, est issu directement de l'adjectif latin *vicinalis* (voisin, du voisinage).

*[Le bon usage: “vicinité” ou “proximité”](https://lecourrierdesetatsunis.com/2011/02/19/le-bon-usage-%E2%80%9Cvicinite%E2%80%9D-ou-%E2%80%9Cproximite%E2%80%9D/)*?, paru dans le courrier des États-Unis en 2011.

Comment: +1 et merci pour ce travail sur un sujet que je ne connais pas. Juste pour ergoter à la toute fin, je ne crois pas qu'on puisse dire le *vicinal* que l'on emploie pour les chemins "dérivé" du substantif *vicinité*. *vicinal* est piqué directement à l'adj. latin *vicina**L**is* déjà employé par Sénèque au sens de *qui relie les villages* http://www.dicolatin.com/XY/LAK/0/VICINALIS/index.htm (*vicinité* étant piqué au subst.  *vicina**T**is*)

Answer (score 10):

> “Vicinité” : peut-on utiliser le mot couramment ?

Non.

> Je me demande pourquoi le mot vicinité n'est pas répertorié dans TLFi.

Parce que le TLF se définit comme *Dictionnaire de la langue du XIX<sup>e</sup> et du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle (1789-1960)*. Il n'a donc pas pour vocation d'inclure des mots disparus des centaines d'années auparavant ni ceux réapparus après : cf. réponse de @Laure.

Comme aCOSωt l'a commenté, *voisinage, environs et proximité* suffisent à notre bonheur.

On peut d'ailleurs mettre en parallèle *voisinage* et *vicinité* en français de leurs pendants anglais *vicinage* et *vicinity* :

[image]

D'après le corpus de Google, on voit que *voisinage* est **six cent fois plus fréquent** aujourd'hui que *vicinité* alors qu'en anglais, c'est *vicinity* qui est deux cent fois plus fréquent que *vicinage*. Il n'y a donc pas photo d'un côté comme de l'autre.

> Son emploi est-il considéré comme un anglicisme (vicinity) ?

Je pense que oui. Il est toujours un peu compliqué de considérer un vieux mot français comme un anglicisme mais il ne fait guère de doute que son (très relatif) retour en grâce est influencé par l'anglais.

Comment: Merci ! Btw, Je pense qu'oui ou que oui ?

Comment: C'est bon. La réponse est ici: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31414/ouistiti-%c3%a9lision-et-liaison (ma question:-)!).